# class attribute declaration

Tags: php, class, object

I didn't use PHP in a while, but I've tried something like this:

```
<?php

class Something {
    public $x = 2 * 3;   // (line 4)
}
```

This code triggers the following error:

> [Wed Feb 13 17:43:56 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/problem.php on line 4

The [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) says

> this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

So, according to the docs, my code should work. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When declaring members of a class you can assign values to them but you can't do complex operations like math or function calls.

```
<?php

class Something {
    public $x = 2 * 3;   // (line 4)
}
```

can be:

```
<?php

class Something {
    public $x = 6;   // (line 4)
}
```

So in your case you'll want to initialize that value in your constructor instead.

```
<?php

class Something {
    public $x; 

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->x = 2 * 3;
    }  
}
```

Comment: yea.. this seems like a dumb "feature" of PHP; using `5242880` doesn't tell it's actually `5MB` for example, and having it in a constructor is even worse. I guess I should pay more attention to the docs next time. Thanks!

Comment: "using `5242880` doesn't tell it's actually `5MB`" that's what comments are for. You should be explaining where your magic numbers are coming from to future you so that it continues to make sense in six months when you come back to debug a niche issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually read carefully the documentation you linked to in the examples it clearly says that this is not allowed:

```
class SimpleClass
{
    // invalid property declarations:
    // (some examples here)
    public $var3 = 1+2;
}
```

This implies that multiplication won't work either.

Answer (score 2):

> So, according to the docs, my code should work.

## nope

The docs clearly state: "it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information"

`2 * 3` is run-time evaluation.

`public $x = 6;` should work.

Comment: well, the docs clearly state `it must be able to be evaluated at compile time` -- 3 * 2 _can_ be evaluated at compile time, but not by PHP it seems (C can do that for example, with global variables), __AND__ it `does not depend on run-time information`.

Comment: @GabiPurcaru, that's a compile-time optimization of run-time operations, in the same way that compiling C# will implicitly use references to the same string reference when identical string literals are used.

Answer (score 0):

Run-time evaluation `2 * 3` is not allowed.

As the [DOCS](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) say

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and **must not** depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.